# Getting the user's IP in Java

Tags: java, spring, ip, vaadin

How can I get the ip address of users who connect to my site located on my server using apache?
I only get the ip address of my server.

```
protected void  getUserIp (){
    try {
        InetAddress ia = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String ipAddr = ia.getHostAddress();
        String hostName = ia.getHostName();
        log.debug("Local IP: " + ipAddr + "and" + "HOST: " + hostName);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect the request headers. In particular, look for the [`X-Forwarded-For` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this code running inside a Spring controller ?

You can add a `HttpServletRequest request` argument to the controller method, which Spring will inject for you, and then you can do `request.getRemoteAddr()`

The `HttpServletRequest` object is coming from the Apache Tomcat

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
UI.getCurrent().getSession().getBrowser().getAddress()
```